# Why ejecting interceptors in axios leaves null in the handlers array

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm curious about something that I have found and want to know why it's the case **and whether it is optimal**.

Take a look at this code snippet

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://test.com",
});

const first = axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((r) => r, (err) => Promise.reject(err));
const second = axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((r) => r, (err) => Promise.reject(err));
```

Simple enough, it adds two interceptors that do nothing (pseudo code just to show the point). But the problem comes (In my opinion) when you eject the interceptor(s).

Like this:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.eject(first);
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.eject(second);
```

And now when `console.log(axiosInstance.interceptors.request);` you will get `{handlers:[null, null]}`

My question is why this happens. Shouldn't we get an empty array instead?

In React apps when a component rerenders and adding these interceptors and ejecting them in effects what would happen in long use of the app?